# Activating text search filtering

Tags: react-admin

I'm learning react admin and I have a simple page w/some filters like so:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { List, TextField, Datagrid, TextInput } from 'react-admin';
import { PostPaginationm } from "./MyPagination";

const postFilters = [
   <TextInput label='Field' source="_Field-Name_matches" alwayson alwaysOn />,
   <TextInput label='Index' source="_Index-Name" alwaysOn />,
   <TextInput label='File' source="_File-Name" alwaysOn />,
   <TextInput label='Db' source="_db-name" alwaysOn />,
   ];

export const IndexFieldSchemaList  = () => (
    <List filters={postFilters} pagination={<PostPaginationm/>}>
        <Datagrid>
        <TextField source="id" label="Id"/>
        <TextField source="_db-name" label="Db"/>
        <TextField source="_File-Name" label="File"/>
        <TextField source="_Index-Seq" label="Seq"/>
        <TextField source="_Index-Name" label="Index"/>
        <TextField source="_Field-Name" label="Field"/>
        <TextField source="_Ascending" label="Asc"/>
        <TextField source="_Abbreviate" label="Abbr"/>
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

When I fill in one of the filters I get the following GET action:

```
GET http://localhost:12537/React/web/table/indexfieldschema?filter={"_File-Name":"extent"}&range=[0,49]&sort=["id","ASC"]
```

Previously I'd get something like this where the "q" field was added to the filter:

```
GET http://localhost:12537/React/web/table/indexfieldschema?filter={"q": "e", "_File-Name":"extent"}&range=[0,49]&sort=["id","ASC"]
```

I've coded the API to work with the "q" specification - w/out that it does a straight equality match which doesn't filter records the way I want.

How do I get the "q" field added to the filter the way I need? I'd note that when I originally coded this it added the "q" field so I'm not sure what changed to stop that behavior.

---

As it turns out the 'q' spec didn't work the way I thought it did and didn't give me the functionality I was after so the answer is how I got what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is taking advantage of the ability to add a "matches" query condition to a field which my backend'll use to do the search I want for each field.

```
const postFilters = [
    <TextInput label='Field' source="_Field-Name_matches" alwayson alwaysOn />,
    <TextInput label='Index' source="_Index-Name_matches" alwayson alwaysOn />,
    <TextInput label='File' source="_File-Name" alwayson  alwaysOn/>,
    <TextInput label='Db' source="_db-name" alwayson  alwaysOn/>
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to name your input "q":

```
const postFilters = [
   <TextInput label="Search" source="q" alwaysOn />
];
```

Comment: If I do that - the filter{} doesn't specify which field to search.

Comment: then the problem is in your dataProvider